# Can i have 2 different jvm.config files say for java11 and java 17 in maven wrapper .mvn folder

Tags: java, maven, java-11, java-17, maven-wrapper

Can i have 2 different jvm.config files say for java11 and java17 in maven wrapper .mvn folder. If possible, can you please point out to the documentation or sample?

My requirement is to add different jvm configs say for java versions like java 11 and java 17

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: I would like to have 2 different configs for jvm arguments to configure. one for java 11 without --add-opens and another for java 16 and above. I want to know if maven wrapper can have 2 different jvm.config files? If yes how?

Comment: Probably not. Sounds like it might be a better idea to fix your modules

Comment: I do see in other build tools like ant, gradle etc we can use multiple config files and pass different vm options for different java versions. I hope its possible with maven too, but just not able to find the right way. Having jvm.config file configuration in maven wrapper folder lead me to think we can have multiple config files, but not sure if there is a way.